# Run Time Error 424 Object Required while exporting data from a listbox to a new workbook

Tags: excel, vba, listbox, runtime-error, export-to-excel

i am trying to export data from a listbox to a new worksheet. It was working until today, i dont know if i did something and i cant see it. Here is my code:

```
    Private Sub Boton_Exportar_Click()


    Dim objexcel As Object
    Dim NombreArchivo As String
    Dim i As Integer, Fila As Integer


    If MsgBox("Seguro que desea exportar en excel?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion) = vbYes Then

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

      Set objexcel = Workbooks.Add
      objexcel.Activate
      NombreArchivo = ActiveWorkbook.Name

    'Asignar los datos del reporte
    Application.Workbooks(NombreArchivo).Worksheets(1).Cells(1, 1) = "Delayed Filter"
    Application.Workbooks(NombreArchivo).Worksheets(1).Cells(1, 2) = Me.ComboBox1

    Application.Workbooks(NombreArchivo).Worksheets(1).Cells(3, 1) = "Vendor"
    Application.Workbooks(NombreArchivo).Worksheets(1).Cells(3, 2) = "PO Number"
    Application.Workbooks(NombreArchivo).Worksheets(1).Cells(3, 3) = "Order Date"
    Application.Workbooks(NombreArchivo).Worksheets(1).Cells(3, 4) = "Part Number"
    Application.Workbooks(NombreArchivo).Worksheets(1).Cells(3, 5) = "Quantity"
    Application.Workbooks(NombreArchivo).Worksheets(1).Cells(3, 6) = "UM"
    Application.Workbooks(NombreArchivo).Worksheets(1).Cells(3, 7) = "Promised Date"
    Application.Workbooks(NombreArchivo).Worksheets(1).Cells(3, 8) = "Due Date"
    Application.Workbooks(NombreArchivo).Worksheets(1).Cells(3, 9) = "Status"


    Fila = 4
    For i = 0 To Me.ListBox1.ListCount - 1

    Application.Workbooks(NombreArchivo).Worksheets(1).Cells(Fila, 1) = Me.ListBox1.List(i, 0)
    Application.Workbooks(NombreArchivo).Worksheets(1).Cells(Fila, 2) = Me.ListBox1.List(i, 1)
    Application.Workbooks(NombreArchivo).Worksheets(1).Cells(Fila, 3) = CDate(Me.ListBox1.List(i, 2))
    Application.Workbooks(NombreArchivo).Worksheets(1).Cells(Fila, 4) = Me.ListBox1.List(i, 3)
    Application.Workbooks(NombreArchivo).Worksheets(1).Cells(Fila, 5) = Format(Me.ListBox1.List(i, 4), "#,###.00")
    Application.Workbooks(NombreArchivo).Worksheets(1).Cells(Fila, 6) = Me.ListBox1.List(i, 5)
    Application.Workbooks(NombreArchivo).Worksheets(1).Cells(Fila, 7) = CDate(Me.ListBox1.List(i, 6))
    Application.Workbooks(NombreArchivo).Worksheets(1).Cells(Fila, 8) = CDate(Me.ListBox1.List(i, 7))
    Application.Workbooks(NombreArchivo).Worksheets(1).Cells(Fila, 9) = Me.ListBox1.List(i, 8)

    Fila = Fila + 1
    Next

    MsgBox "Los datos han sido exportados", vbInformation

End If

End Sub
```

The line that is getting highlighted is **"objexcel.Activate"**

Comment: I recommend giving [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba) a read through. You almost never need to Select or Activate anything. It would be better to use a workbook object and work through that.

Comment: Thank you, i appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No clue why the `Activate`-statement fails, but it is not necessary at all. A newly created workbook gets active automatically, but it is even not necessary to have it active. The variable `objExcel` is already set to the new workbook, so you can use it. I would advice to declare it as `Workbook` (not as object), also the name should be changed (but that's up to you).

You could use something like

```
Dim newWorkbook As Workbook
Set newWorkbook = Workbooks.Add

newWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(1, 1) = "Delayed Filter"
newWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(1, 2) = Me.ComboBox1
...
```

or

```
With newWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
    .Cells(1, 1) = "Delayed Filter"
    .Cells(1, 2) = Me.ComboBox1
    ...
End With
```

Comment: Hi, i did the changes but now it says "Run-time Error '-2147221080 (800401a8)': Method 'Worksheets' of objects '_Workbook' Failed:

Dim NewWorkbook As Workbook
Dim i As Integer, Row As Integer


If MsgBox("Seguro que desea exportar en excel?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion) = vbYes Then
  
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  
  Set NewWorkbook = Workbooks.Add

    With NewWorkbook.Worksheets(1)

the *With newWorkbook.worksheets(1)* is getting highlighted

Comment: Have no clue, never saw that error. Change the line creating the Workbook to `Application.Workbooks.Add` and see if that helps. Also, put a break point to the statement after the creation and if code stops there, inspect the content of the `newWorkbook` variable in the  *Locals Window* (View->Locals)

Comment: Hi, thank you @FunThomas , i fixed the error with `Dim WbName as string` ,`WbName = ActiveWorkbook.Name` and `Application.Workbooks(WbName).Worksheets(1)`

Answer (score 0):

Try to declare the object as Excel `Workbook`:

```
Dim objexcel As Excel.Workbook
'
Set objexcel = Workbooks.Add
```